# Multiple background color in canvas Fabricjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Hi is posible to add two background color in canvas using fabricjs something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't able to use multiple background for canvas but we dynamically create background and apply color fabric js allow to apply gradient to the object   Like this..

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");

var bgrect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  width: canvas.getWidth(),
  height: canvas.getHeight(),
  selectable:false
});


bgrect.setGradient('fill', {
  x1: 0,
  y1: 0,
  x2: 0,
  y2: bgrect.height,
  colorStops: {
    0: "rgba(163,125,68,1)",
    0.5:"rgba(163,125,68,1)",
    0.51:"rgba(153,29,29,1)",
    1: "rgba(153,29,29,1)"
  }
});

canvas.add(bgrect)
bgrect.sendToBack();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Now that you make me think of it a background feature as gradient should be added to fabricjs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes using css gradient it is possible. I have created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsalaat/hXzvk/181/) for you with these colors as background.

```
canvas {
  background: rgba(163,125,68,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(163,125,68,1) 0%, rgba(158,115,51,1) 50%, rgba(158,17,17,1) 51%, rgba(153,29,29,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(163,125,68,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(158,115,51,1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(158,17,17,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(153,29,29,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(163,125,68,1) 0%, rgba(158,115,51,1) 50%, rgba(158,17,17,1) 51%, rgba(153,29,29,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(163,125,68,1) 0%, rgba(158,115,51,1) 50%, rgba(158,17,17,1) 51%, rgba(153,29,29,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(163,125,68,1) 0%, rgba(158,115,51,1) 50%, rgba(158,17,17,1) 51%, rgba(153,29,29,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(163,125,68,1) 0%, rgba(158,115,51,1) 50%, rgba(158,17,17,1) 51%, rgba(153,29,29,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a37d44', endColorstr='#991d1d', GradientType=0 );
}
```

The gradient css is generated from [cssmatic](http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator#'%5C-moz%5C-linear%5C-gradient%5C%28top%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28163%5C%2C125%5C%2C68%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%200%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28158%5C%2C115%5C%2C51%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2050%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28158%5C%2C17%5C%2C17%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2051%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28153%5C%2C29%5C%2C29%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%20100%5C%25%5C%29%5C%3B').

Hope it helps.

Comment: Its bad solution becouse I need to change color of background using colorpicker

Comment: Its not a bad solution. Its a bad question. You should have mentioned that in the Question, and either way it is possible to change css through javascript from colorPicker. But for different color background this gradient css is the best solution.

Comment: having background color set with style will not allow you to export the content to other image o to svg, neither serialize it with json.